# "\xC3" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Regards!

I have this in a service made in Ruby On Rails:

```
@file = File.new doc.path_to_file_prueba(id_fac_elect) || doc.path_to_file, 'w:ISO-8859-1'
...
@file << xml
@file.close
```

This error is shown:

```
"\xC3" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1
```

xml is a text string that contains a "Ñ" character, and that generate the error.

Somebody have idea why is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Certainly a problem with encoding. Try converting the xml to ISO-8859-1 (which is the same mode as your file) before appending it's content.

Comment: It worked half.  now, the character changed from "Ñ" to "Ã‘".   "FINCA DOÑA FATIMA S.A.S." became "FINCA DOÃ‘A FATIMA S.A.S."

Comment: Encoding is not my expertise. Do you have to write de file as 'w:ISO-8859-1'? Couldn't it be UTF-8 instead? Maybe somebody else will be able to help you further.

Comment: I did it. I encoded in UTF-8 and the character became "Ã‘" too.